# How to include code from parent project in module of maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have parent project P with some class A, and some xml files in resources folder
and a module M inside project P.

Class X in Module M needs class A, but I cant import it. In class X, i see `"cant resolve symbol class A"`

Is there any way I can use the existing code from project P in module M?

Comment: A parent Maven project is a `pom` project, more like an umbrella for the modules. What do you mean by "parent project P with class A" ?

Comment: it is some class in Project P

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024320/maven-include-parent-classes